# Running reclassify and Int tools on raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, reclassify, error-999999

I am trying to do a very simple thing - convert a raster to a polygon where positive values are one set of polygons, and negative values are another set of polygons. The raster ranges from a minimum value of -8.00857 to a maximum of 9.4592.
Here's what I have tried:

1. Convert floating point Raster to Int (Int does not work).
2. Multiply raster by a large number to remove decimal places then Convert Raster to Int (Int does not work)
3. Reclassify into two classes: 0 for negative, 1 for positive (Reclassify does not work)

   4. Extract positive and negative values using Extract by Attribute and then apply steps 1-3 to them. Extract by attribute works, but none of steps 1-3 work.

The error messages do not indicate why the tools are not working.

Comment: Here is a link to the file on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MXyY3wN6pU9hY23fBPxeiRJHH5YUKLwE

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for just two polygons... Suppose your raster is a mix of positive/negative values distributed throughout the raster with no clearly defined zones?

Comment: Reclass worked just fine using your data.  What is your error message?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When I say two polygons I mean two sets of polygons. One set of negative polygons and another set of positive polygons.

Comment: @GBG the error message is 999999: Error executing function. May I ask how you entered the 'old classes' in order to have the tool work successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The following parameters resulted in a successful reclassification of your data.  I also found [Trouble with Reclassify tool](https://community.esri.com/thread/21040) when I did a Google search on 999999 error using reclassify.[image: reclass paramaters]

Comment: This is exactly what I have done and it does not work. How strange, I cannot think what else could be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I may just restart my analysis from the beginning and see if I run into the same issue.

Comment: Alright I just got it working. All I changed was the directory where I was saving it. Must be some kind of pathway issue. Thank you again.